# How can I tell if file is writable from script?

Tags: php, file-io, error-handling

My plugin needs to be able to write to the file system. Is it possible to query a known file for write permissions?

For example, my wordpress theme ships with a file called custom.css that i need write access to. When my theme first loads, I'd like to query this script to see if its writable, then echo the results to my theme.

Then in support session's, I can ask the user to visually check this setting to insure I have write permissions as expected (and eliminate that as the cause of a read/write issue).

Comment: "It's easier to beg forgiveness than ask permission." -- if writing is needed, one approach is just to try and write and react accordingly. This works best if you're already at the "should write" phase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is_writable("yourfilename.txt")`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

For example...

```
if (is_writable('custom.css')) {
    echo "Success!  custom.css is writable";
} else {
    echo "Failure!! custom.css is not writable";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably way too late for this but there is "is_writable"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Comment: Reminds me of the kid in class who raises his hand just after someone else correctly answers the question and says, "I was gonna say is_writable?"

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php